# Enhance the reputation system by analyzing the reputation of question's author

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I propose to analyze the reputation of an author of question, so that if I answered an question which was posted by a user with reputation `>N` then I would receive more than `+15` for `Accept Answer`.

I was thinking about it because now there are a lot questions from newbies which are easy to answer, but a lot of really non-trivial questions stay unanswered which often come from "Guru's", so let's motivate people to answer really hard questions ;)

Answer (score 14):

Very good questions are often asked by very low-rep users, while a Guru can ask a trivial question if they have forgot something they need to know quickly. There is no real correlation between the "hardness" of a question, and the author's reputation.

It's an interesting idea, but it's not going to work in this form.

Comment: High-rep users can also ask very basic questions in tags they're totally new to when picking up new skills.

Comment: @Bill yeah. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script